# Django authentication new

Tags: python, django, authentication, web

I've been trying to make a login in django like we do in other programming language . I know it's a framework but instead of using Django's default 'user' model i've defined my own called companyUsers so it has 'id' as primary key. So i need an alternate system to Login.I didn't understan What's exact purpose of Django back end. I just need to make the user login with valid credential .I referred chatGpt even if somebody has any idea to write a login without using User model and default athentication system ,

I'm expecting a login code like normal.

Comment: I think this page may be of help: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/customizing/
Which explains how to check for a user in the DB and how to give the user a session.

Comment: I recommend reading the following article (link below). Django has a few different ways to deal with your requirements. You can use a proxy model for changing the standard model' behavior. You can extend the AbstractUser model with fields of your choice and then make a 1-to-1 relationship with the standard model, and you can even create your own by referencing the AbstractBaseUser model.  https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/article/2021/07/08/what-you-should-know-about-the-django-user-model.html

Answer (score 0):

Here I tried to implement custom `login` and `logout` functionality without using the Django User model, here I wrote the base code for custom `(login and logout)` functionality. you can customize according to your requirement

#### models.py

```py
from django.db import models
# Create your models here.

class UserModel(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()
    password = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

#### views.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import *
from .serializers import *
from django.contrib import messages

def login_checker(request,email,password,):
    is_logged_in = UserModel.objects.filter(email=email,password=password,is_active=True)
    user = None
    if is_logged_in.exists():
        request.session['user'] = {'email':is_logged_in[0].email,'password':is_logged_in[0].password,'is_active':is_logged_in[0].is_active}
        user = request.session['user']
    else:
        user=None
    return user
    
def LoginView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = login_checker(request,email,password)
        if user is not None:
            messages.success(request,'Login success')
            return redirect('/default/')
        else:
            messages.error(request,'Login failed!')

    context = {'form':'form'}
    return render(request,'index.html',context)

def DefaultView(request):
    return render(request,'singlestory.html')

def LogoutView(request):
    request.session.pop('user')
    messages.success(request,'Logout success')
    return redirect('/')
```

#### Working...

[image]

Comment: Do not store passwords uncrypted.